# CYOA Game in Android - Retrieving Story and Button Choices from Text file

Tags: java, android, text

So I am doing a Create Your Own Adventure game/book in for an Android class for a final project. The way I have it set up is with two activities (A menu and a page layout). I have a "Master File" text file that has the relationships between each page (example below). I also have the "pages" setup in text files that need to be retrieved and then set to the TextView and the 3 buttons. (example below of how they are setup.

My question is how am I supposed to retrieve that information correctly.

I want to have it setup that when the Page class does an OnCreate it fills in the textview and the 3 buttons from the correct Page.txt file.

This is my page.class the code for the pages.

```
public class pages extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<FileRelationship> fileRelationships;
FileRelationship selectedRelationship;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page);

    fileRelationships = new ArrayList<FileRelationship>();

    String MasterLine;

    InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.MasterFile);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

    // Creates the arrayList of all the relationships for later use of retreival.
    try {
        while (( MasterLine = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] MasterLineArray = MasterLine.split(",");
            String filename = MasterLineArray[0];
            String choice1 = MasterLineArray[1];
            String choice2 = MasterLineArray[2];
            String choice3 = MasterLineArray[3];

            FileRelationship fr = new FileRelationship(filename, choice1, choice2, choice3);

            fileRelationships.add(fr);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    TextView storyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storyText);

    Button choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstchoice);
    choice1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findRelationship(selectedRelationship.firstLink);
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    });

    Button choice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondchoice);
    choice2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findRelationship(selectedRelationship.secondLink);
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    });

    Button choice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thirdchoice);
    choice3.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findRelationship(selectedRelationship.thirdLink);
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    });

        // **THIS IS THAT PART I NEED HELP WITH THE MOST** I dont know what
    // to put in the setText part to have it retrieve the correct information.

    storyText.setText();
    choice1.setText();
    choice2.setText();
    choice3.setText();

}

    public void findRelationship(String nextFileName) {
        int pageIndex = fileRelationships.indexOf((new FileRelationship(nextFileName)));
        selectedRelationship = fileRelationships.get(pageIndex);
    }
}
```

This is my FileRelationship class, that I use to create the array in my page class.

```
public class FileRelationship {
String fileName;
String firstLink;
String secondLink;
String thirdLink;

public  FileRelationship(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public  FileRelationship(String fileName, String firstLink, String secondLink, String thirdLink) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.firstLink = firstLink;
    this.secondLink = secondLink;
    this.thirdLink = thirdLink;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if(this == o) {
        return true;
    }

    if(o instanceof FileRelationship) {
        return this.fileName.equals(((FileRelationship)o).fileName);
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

This is how my MasterFile.txt is setup to define the relationships (Just an example)

```
Page1,Page2,Page3,Page4
Page2,Page5,Page6,Page7
Page3,Page8,Page9,Page10
```

And finally this is how my Page1,Page2,Page3 etc. will be setup (Again just an example)

```
This is a practice story line, my pages text will go into here and create the story in this way.
Choice 1
Choice 2
Choice 3
```

Is the best way to create a method that retrieves the information from the selectedRelationship and then puts all 4 of them into strings? If so how can this be done. I also am not sure if my FindRelationship method is correct either.

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like I have everything else correct, but I wasn't also sure if I am retrieving the MasterFile parts correctly and putting it into the array list correctly either. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!